# Why this won't show keyboard on iPhone even when obj.focus() is used?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

Javascript 1 is the action that will be invoked when a link is clicked.
It's working perfectly and it sets the value automatically, and focus the element.
Of course, iPhone's virtual keyboard appears because input text field is focused.

**Javascript 1**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a#user', function()  {
        $(".box#input").val($(this).attr('value')); 
        var input = $(".box#input");
        $(document).scrollTop(input .offset().top - 45);
        input.focus();          
    });
 });
```

This Javascript 2 is the action that will be invoked when URL contains `mode=1` and when it's loaded.
This script does pretty much the same as above and working fine.
But one thing!! iPhone's keyboard won't appear even though input text field is focused.
It's really strange... Why? and How can I fix this?

**Javascript 2**

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.URL.indexOf("mode=1") >= 0){ 
        var input = $(".box#input");
        $(document).scrollTop(input .offset().top - 45);
        var v = input.val();
        input.val('');
        input.focus().val(v);
        input.focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the keyboard will not show unless there is some kind of user interaction (eg. clicking on an input field). You can however do this programmatically as you did above if you use a timeout.

```
setTimout(function(){
    input.focus();
}, 1);
```

Comment: Could you show me the whole code with both my code and your code?

Comment: That does not work on my iPod touch. I'd be surprised if it worked on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

input.focus() will activate the keyboard if you add the web page to the iOS home screen and access it from there